# Any STL doubly linked implemenations with pointer to head instead of previous

Tags: c++

Is there an doubly linked list implementation in c++ that allows modification to the previous pointer.  For example instead of the previous pointer pointing to the previous node, it can be modified to point to the front of the list, and thus all one will have to do is call previous to get directly to the head of a list.

Comment: You mean you want to delete everything from the front up to your element?

Comment: That seems like a really odd way to use a doubly-linked list. [What are you really trying to do](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: Implement it yourself. Standard library has `std::list` as doubly-linked list, but it will not allow you to play with the nodes it internally maintains.

Comment: why don't you directly access the head?

Comment: +1 @In silico.  You presumably already *have* the head pointer available to you at all times - why would you need a copy in each node?

Comment: Given just an iterator to the node, if you want to access the head in constant time rather than iterating backwards.

Comment: @asdfasdfasdf asdas: I can't think of a situation where accessing the head node given only an iterator to it is required. Care to elaborate?

Comment: The linkedlist implementation of Kruskals with Find Set

Answer (score 0):

If you want the head of an STL list, just call `list<>::begin()`.  A pointer to the head of the list is stored by the usual implementations, and if you literally need it to be a pointer, just say `&myList.front()` (check for empty first!).